# Does emacs have a way to render https link previews?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm looking for a way to generate web link previews inside of emacs, especially inside of an org-mode document.

To be more specific with what I'm trying to do:

I'd like to compile a list of tweets, but actually see the tweets inline, on the page. Whether that's simply pasting the https link, or even the HTML to embed a link preview would both work, but I'm struggling to make that work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might be looking for the same thing, I couldn't find anything like this at the time of posting, so I ended up writing a quick package for it: https://github.com/aviaviavi/link-preview.el.